# Is there a way to make all external links from my site appear in a new tab within react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware you can usually add target=_blank to have one off links appear in a new tab, but is there a way to make all links on the site that are not internal open into a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper function in each of your links / hrefs that compares the url of your project(window.location.host) with the url that is in the link. If the url is not a path on your project use _blank.